# Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: kotlin, java-io, illegalargumentexception

I have a function inside of a larger project that is called on startup via another function. Here's the code for it:

```
val infoDoc = File("res/info.txt")

private fun readInfo(): MutableList<Reminder> {
    val reminders = mutableListOf<Reminder>()
    infoDoc.forEachLine {
        //...
    }
    return reminders
}
```

However, when I attempt to run it, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine, parameter $receiver
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine(FileReadWrite.kt)
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine$default(FileReadWrite.kt:154)
    at main.IoKt.readInfo(io.kt:22)
    at main.IoKt.read(io.kt:8)
    at main.AppKt.<clinit>(app.kt:23)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Note that `Reminder` is a custom class, and that `infoDoc` is declared in `app.kt`. I can provide any other code that is required.

**Edit:** There are checks in place to make sure that `info.txt` exists, and is readable/writable.

Comment: Somehow `infoDoc` is `null` at that line. Given the code shown, it definitely shouldn't happen, so there is something relevant missing from it. Is it initialized just before the function, as shown? Maybe there is another variable called `infoDoc` which shadows it? What happens if you move the `val infoDoc` line inside the function?

My guess would be that `readInfo` gets called from a method in superclass constructor, except the stack trace says otherwise.

Comment: "There are checks in place to make sure that info.txt exists, and is readable/writable."
None of that would make `infoDoc` null, the exception would be different.

Comment: Maybe there is a loop where `io.kt` also tries to access `app.kt` during initialization?

Comment: I think you did understand message wrong. null is one of two arguments of `forEachLine` method. It has to arguments — charset and block. Please, try to provide charset explicitly.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov (1) `infoDoc` is declared in `app.kt`. (2) Giving additional information because of useless answer. (3) I don't understand...

Comment: @asm0dey I will try that, but previously (multiple projects and uses) this has not been a problem so I'm not sure...

Comment: Looks strange for me too, but that's the only place where this exception can happen. The other possibility is old version of kotlin, but looks strange too

Comment: @asm0dey Okay then. My Kotlin shouldn't be out of date unless Intellij stopped searching for language updates automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception happens because `infoDoc` is not initialized yet. Initializers in Kotlin are executed from top to bottom, so it looks like the initializer of a property declared above `infoDoc` in `app.kt` is calling the `readInfo` function.

To fix the problem, move the declaration of `infoDoc` above the place where `readInfo` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Check if info.txt exists, or try the absolute file path.

Comment: I have checks in place so that it throws errors if my files don't exist, or can't be read/written.